# GSON: serialize/deserialize object of class, that have registered type hierarchy adapter, using ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.Adapter

Tags: java, gson

To be clear, let introduse some model:

```java
interface A {
    boolean isSomeCase();
}

class AAdapter implements JsonSerializer<A> {
    public JsonElement serialize(A src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        if (src.isSomeCase()) {
            /* some logic */
            return result;
        } else {
            JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
            JsonElement valueJson = <???>; // TODO serialize src like POJO
            json.add(src.getClass().getSimpleName(), valueJson);
            return json;
        } 
    }
}

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(A.class. new AAdapter())
        .create();
```

How it is possible to serealize some instance of `A`, which `isSomeCase()` = `false`, like any other object, that is serialized by `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.Adapter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom [TypeAdapterFactory](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html) and handle incoming object's `isSomeCase()` result in its [TypeAdapter](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html)'s `write()` method and apply your logic there:

```
public class ATypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    public TypeAdapter<A> create(Gson gson, TypeToken type) {
        if (!A.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawType())) {
            // Check if incoming raw type is an instance of A interface
            return null;
        } 

        final TypeAdapter<A> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);

        return new TypeAdapter<A>() {

            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter out, A value) throws IOException {
                if(value.isSomeCase()) {
                    // your custom logic here
                    out.beginObject();
                    out.name("x").value(0);
                    out.endObject();
                } else {
                    // default serialization here
                    delegate.write(out, value);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public A read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                return delegate.read(in);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
// Register custom type adapter factory
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapterFactory(new ATypeAdapterFactory());
final Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

A aSomeCaseTrue = new AImpl(true);
System.out.print("aSomeCaseTrue:" + gson.toJson(aSomeCaseTrue));
// writes; aSomeCaseTrue:{"x":0}


A aSomeCaseFalse = new AImpl(false);
System.out.print("aSomeCaseFalse:" + gson.toJson(aSomeCaseFalse););
// writes; aSomeCaseFalse:{"someCase":false}
```

**Extras:**

1) Your interface:

```
interface A {
    boolean isSomeCase();
}
```

2) A sample class which implements your sample interface:

```
class AImpl implements A {
    boolean someCase;

    public AImpl(boolean value) {
        this.someCase = value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSomeCase() {
        return someCase;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already solved problem this way (using `TypeAdapterFactory`). But you've introduced `getDelegateAdapter` method. I've used to use version 2.1, where it is absend. So you've made my code cleaner. Thanks a lot!