# How to use Gson TypeAdapter with an object mocked by Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, gson, mockito

I would like to mock an object passed into Gson via TypeAdapter like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SceneExporterTest {

@Test
public void testWriter() {
    List<SceneObject> sceneObjects = mockSceneObjects();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(SceneObject.class, new SceneExporter()).create();

    String s = gson.toJson(sceneObjects); //This method ends up with an exception.
}

private List<SceneObject> mockSceneObjects() {
    List<SceneObject> sceneObjects = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        sceneObjects.add(mockSceneObject(i));
    }
    return sceneObjects;
}

private SceneObject mockSceneObject(int i) {
    SceneObject sceneObject = mock(SceneObject.class);
    //...
    return sceneObject;
}

}
```

My type adapter:

```
public class SceneExporter extends TypeAdapter<SceneObject> {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, SceneObject value) throws IOException {
        out.name("position");
        out.value(toValue(value.getPosition()));
        out.name("scale");
        out.value(toValue(value.getScale()));
        out.name("rotation");
        out.value(toValue(value.getRotation()));
    }

    @Override
    public SceneObject read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But I end up which such exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: com.editor.api.scene.objects.SceneObject. Forgot to register a type adapter?
```

Scene object is pretty heavy object and I don't want to instantinate it normally within test. So is there a possibility to just mock it? I also would like not to use Spies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The runtime type of an instance of `SceneObject` created in this way: `mock(SceneObject.class)` is `SceneObject$MockitoMock$<SOMEID>`.

The  runtime type of an instance of `SceneObject` created in this way: `new SceneObject()` is `SceneObject`.

So, when Gson's `TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper` looks for a registered `TypeAdapter` in its context for a mocked object it will not find one because your `SceneExporter` has been registered against `SceneObject.class`.

What this is really saying is that a mocked `SceneObject` is not **of type** `SceneObject` (it is actually a sub class of `SceneObject`) hence Gson will not find your bespoke type adapter.

If you declare `Gson` like this ...

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(mock(SceneObject.class).getClass(), new SceneExporter()).create();
```

... then it **will** find your bespoke type adapter but that registration looks 'off' doesn't it? It feels like a test-only specialisation.

If you really **must** mock `SceneObject` then I think you'll need to register an [inheritance aware type adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592904/gson-serialize-deserialize-object-of-class-that-have-registered-type-hierarchy#26596808) but if you are doing that just to support this test case then that feels like a test-only limitation bleeding into the 'main' source tree. So, perhaps the simplest solutions are:

- Create real instances of `SceneObject`
- Use a Mockito `Spy` to stub out the specific `SceneObject` getters which are invoked in `SceneExporter`